# ios serializing xml file into nsmutable dictionary where xml has multiple atributes

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to serialize a xml like this:

```
<Rows>
<RowOne SKATERID="706" MANUFACTURER="A-DZG" ISFACT="F" ISSKATE="F">True</RowOne>
<RowTwo SKATERID="318" MANUFACTURER="A-FGW" ISFACT="F" ISSKATE="T">True</RowTwo>
<RowThree SKATERID="458" MANUFACTURER="A-OPJ" ISFACT="F" ISSKATE="T">False</RowThree>
<RowFour SKATERID="178" MANUFACTURER="A-JSL" ISFACT="F" ISSKATE="T">True</RowFour>
</Rows>
```

But my question is what would be the best way of doing it including the atributes. So far I have my parser working and when I detect the node has attributes I'm sending those to a local nsmutabledictionay. but my question is how do I map the dictonary of attibutes and the value of the node. for example in RowOne the value is true bute it has the following attibutes SKATERID="706" MANUFACTURER="A-DZG" ISFACT="F" ISSKATE="F" .

in -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

I have this like of code:

```
if ([attributeDict count] != 0) {
    self.myDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:attributeDict];
}

in -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
```

I want to figure out what would be the best way of serializing the dictionary with the value of the node

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: How about showing your current code and your desired result.

Comment: I'd like it if HelenaM would give me my checkmark for her previous question where I gave her the solution to use didStartElement =P

Comment: The xcode, iphone, and ipad tags are not relevant to your question. That is why they are being removed.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
After re-reading your question, what do you mean by "serialize"? Pending your answer the solution below may not be what you desired.

If your XML attributes are static I would recommend creating a custom class, myRowClass, that operates like this...

```
myRow.SkaterID //NSString
myRow.Manufacturer //NSString
myRow.IsFact //BOOL
myRow.IsSkate //BOOL
```

With that custom class you can push each myRow object into your NSMutableDictionary like this...

```
[myDict setObject:myRow forKey:@"RowOne"]
myRow = nil;
myRowClass *myRow = [[myRowClass alloc]init];
<...Iterate through next XML Node...>
[myDict setObject:myRow forKey:@"RowTwo"]
```

Then when you need to access your data you can retrieve it like this...

```
NSString *myCurrentSkaterID = [[myDict objectForKey:@"RowTwo"].SkaterID]
```

or

```
myRowClass *myCurrentRow = [[myRowClass alloc]init];
myCurrentRow = [myDict objectForKey:@"RowTwo"];
NSString *myCurrentSkaterID = myCurrentRow.SkaterID;
```

Comment: what i meant to say is I want to have a nsmutabledictionary with all the content of the xml in such a way like if was a json file.

Comment: do you mind typing out an example of what your desired output is as @wain recommended earlier?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/